# Find free time with google calendar api

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to check if there is a free time (without events) in some interval of time on Google Calendar. There is a [freebusy](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query) Google API, but it returns an array of events with dates.

```
"busy": [
    {
         "start": "2015-10-08T16:00:00+02:00",
         "end": "2015-10-08T20:00:00+02:00"
    },
    {
        "start": "2015-10-09T15:00:00+02:00",
        "end": "2015-10-09T16:00:00+02:00"
    },
]
```

Is there any simple way to get 'true/false' information about free time (some feature to google api)? If no, maybe you know some easy way to manually iterate by "busy" array and check if there is some empty space between events.

Answer (score 10):

[Freebusy.query](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query) supports `timeMin` and `timeMax` values. Set those two values to encompass the timeslot you are interested in and if the response returns zero events in that timeslot you have the answer of free time.

```
{
  "timeMin": datetime,
  "timeMax": datetime,
}
```

Comment: This is what a datetime would look like: 2019-04-12T09:30:00-06:30 (see https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/error/InvalidRFC3339Date.html for more)