# Finding free slots on multiple calendars

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm writing a script that will, given parameters for start/end datetimes, find the first mutually available timeslot on two different calendars in order to book a meeting.

The script I have so far is running really slowly. I'm guessing this is because I'm looping through both calendars in 30 minute increments and running CalendarApp.getCalendarById(email).getEvents each time to see if there's a free 30-minute timeslot.

I've thought about running a batch operation using .getEvents() once to minimize the number of reads but I get stuck here because the result is an array with busy timeslots, whereas I'm trying to find free timeslots.

Is there a better way to approach this to make my script run faster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find free time with google calendar api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053293/find-free-time-with-google-calendar-api)

Answer (score 0):

## Find Open Time Slots

I've done something similar to this recently and what I did was to create and object similar to something like this:

```
var timeSlotsObj={"8:00-8:30":0,"8:30-9:00":0,"9:00-9:30":0,"9:30-10:00":0,...."7:30-8:00":0,slotA["8:00-8:30","8:30-9:00",...]}
```

Then I went through each calendar and incremented the timeslot value for each event **on a given day** which overlapped that time slot in each calendar.  After that I took the slotsA array and looped through it looking for any timeSlot that still had 0 in it.

The loop looks like the following:

```
for(var i=0;i<timeSlotObj.slotA.length;i++){
  if(timeSlotsObj[timeSlotsObj.slotA[i]]==0){
    //You just found an empty time slot and it's value is timeSlotsObj.slotA[i]
  }
```

Any object property that still 0 as it's value is an open time slot for the given set of calendars on any given day.

- [Javascript Object Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

In my case I actually used Date Objects as the Object Properties or Keys but the idea is the same.  Whatever slots have no events in them are free slots.